# Memory not being freed with Julia

Tags: memory, julia, garbage-collection

I'm running the following code in Julia on Ubuntu, and I can't manage to get my memory freed (as reported by `top` or the System Monitor).

```
struct Container
    field::Vector{Matrix{Float64}}
end
function f!(x::Container)
    push!(x.field, randn(10, 10000))
end
function g!(x::Container, n::Int64)
    for _ in 1:n
        f!(x)
    end
end

X = randn(10, 10000);
c = Container([X]);
g!(c, 10000)
GC.gc()
# c is about 7.5GiB in size now, and I have about 8.3GB in memory occupied.

c = nothing
GC.gc()
# Memory usually isn't freed here, sometimes it is partially.
```

If I keep running the middle snippet over and over again:

```
X = randn(10, 10000);
c = Container([X]);
g!(c, 10000)
GC.gc()
```

The memory usage fluctuates between 60 and 80 % of my total memory (32 GB). Which makes me suspect that in fact Julia is clearing memory on its own terms and my calls to `gc` are useless. I'm guessing Julia is keeping the memory to optimize in case I call `g!` again, because I can't see what variable could be holding all that memory.

My worry is if I have similar code running on multiple Julia workers, I'm going to find myself in trouble even if I clear the variable `c`. Is my worry justified or should I trust that Julia will effectively clear memory when it needs to?

Comment: 1. `GC.gc()` should do nothing when you first call it because there's no memory to reclaim. 2. When you call it the second time there is still no memory to reclaim, but there is a new variable `chain = nothing`. Should that be `c = nothing`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Sorry, yes that was a typo on my part, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version on Julia are you using? I copy pasted your code in 1.9.2, just before GC.gc() the memory was 7.5GB and it dropped to 117 MB after the call. This is on Windows 10.

Comment: I just updated to 1.9.2 and still the same issue. I guess this must be Ubuntu not reporting free memory correctly.